# Can substitution rules be used in function definitions?

Tags: function-construction, replacement

Simple input like this

```
f[x_]:=2x
f[2]
```

has the predicted output of 4. However, this

```
r={a->2x};
f[x_] := a/.r
f[2]
```

Produces the output "2 x". I would like it to produce 4. More generally, is there a way I can incorporate rules into a function definition?

Comment: `f[x_] = a /. r`.

Comment: it's not a problem with using rules in the def; it's a problem of whether `x` literally appears in the rhs or not. When applying a definition where the pattern `x_` on the lhs has been matched to an argument, e.g. `2`, mathematica looks to see if the pattern name `x` appears anywhere in the definition's rhs, substitutes, *then* evaluates. Here it only sees `a`, `/.`, and `r`, and no `x`, so it doesn't substitute anything and finishes its application of the definition. All further evaluation "doesn't know about" the definition anymore. Further...

Comment: ...when you use `:=`, the rhs you typed in is unevaluated, and the definition mathematica learns is the replacement rule`f[x_] :> a /. r`. When you use `=`, the rhs is evaluated first, and *then* learned as a definition—so we start with `f[x_] = a /. r`, `a /. r` becomes `2x`, *then* the definition that mathematica learns is the rule `f[x_] :> 2x`. That's why cvgmt's solution works. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18487#18487) for more about the difference between `:=` and `=` :)

Comment: @thorimur Please turn your comments into an actual answer! It's obviously too long for a comment, as evidenced by the fact that you had to use two :-) It's great insight into what's going wrong, in addition to how to make it right.

Comment: @MarcoB Haha, you're absolutely right. And thanks! I've turned them into an answer now. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a problem with using rules in the def; it's a problem of whether `x` literally appears in the rhs or not.

When applying a definition where the pattern `x_` on the lhs has been matched to an argument (e.g. `2`), Mathematica looks to see if the pattern name `x` appears anywhere in the definition's rhs, substitutes the matched value for any `x`'s it finds, then evaluates. Here, it looks at `f[2]` and matches `2` to `x_`, then looks at the rhs of the definition, and only sees `a`, `/.`, and `r` (and no `x`). So, it doesn't substitute anything, and finishes its application of the definition. All further evaluation (of `a /. r`) "doesn't know about" the definition anymore. (In particular, it doesn't know about he value `2` that got matched to `x`, and `x` is now "just a symbol again".)

Further, when you use `:=`, the rhs you typed in is unevaluated, and the definition Mathematica learns is the replacement rule `f[x_] :> a /. r`. However, when you use `=`, the rhs is evaluated first, and *then* learned as a definition. So we start with `f[x_] = a /. r`, `a /. r` becomes `2x`, then the definition that Mathematica learns is the rule `f[x_] :> 2x`. That's why cvgmt's solution in the comments (`f[x_] = a /. r`) works. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18487#18487) for more about the difference between `:=` and `=` :)

(Note: I omitted some of the technicalities when describing what rule Mathematica actually learns and how it uses the rule, but all in all, it behaves roughly like `:>`.)